# Apache Conditional RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have moved a website from /blog/ to the web root. I created a RedirectMatch 301 for my URLs which I believe is correct:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1
```

This works correctly. Now, domain.tld/blog/foo/ redirects to domain.tld/foo/

However, there is one issue. There is a page on the website with the slug: /blog/

Now you can't access the page since domain.tld/blog/ redirects to domain.tld/

So what I would like to accomplish is not to redirect /blog/, but to redirect /blog/everything/else/

domain.tld/blog/ no redirection

domain.tld/blog/foo/ redirects to domain.tld/foo/

domain.tld/blog/foo/bar/ redirects to domain.tld/foo/bar/
Etc.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? I think it needs a little change:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1
```

Remember to clear cache + history on browsers before testing, browsers remember 301 redirect rules.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Only need change (.*) to (.+).