# htaccess Redirect excluding pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is related to: [Apache Conditional RedirectMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718903/apache-conditional-redirectmatch)

I am redirecting /blog to the root (/)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.+)$ /$1
```

This works correctly:

/blog/ - no redirection

/blog/foo/ - redirects to domain.tld/foo/

/blog/foo/bar/ - redirects to domain.tld/foo/bar/
Etc.

I would like to make one modification. My pagination urls are domain.tld/blog/page/1, domain.tld/blog/page/2, etc and they should not redirect.

How can I prevent /blog/page/ from redirecting?
Thank you!

Comment: For reference, you are using to unrelated Apache modules here. RewriteEngine and RewriteBase are only needed if you are using RewriteCond and/or RewriteRule.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/((?!page/[0-9]).+)$ /$1
```

This will not redirect

- /blog/page/id